# replacing the sound a small toy speaker makes

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, materials, plastic

not sure if this counts for this community, and im open to suggestions where this would belong but im looking for advice.

i have no experience in working with physical hardware, as the limited experience i have with engineering has all been via digital resources. i am currently trying to change the sound that this toy (called the 'sing a ma jig', this model is from 2010)

heres a link containing photos of the mechanism, it seems pretty simple as it just connects to two AAA batteries. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15P05_pvBiocYCeZ8LYKHPqI_Ro12i7UC

i tried looking on youtube and reddit but didnt find anything that worked, as i dont know the model of this speaker nor the type of chip that it uses (though it looks similair to that of other toy chips). the numbers on the back of the speaker have eroded with age and there is some yellowing, which has caused the speaker to be muffled.

if anyone has any advice id love to hear it!! (also this was posted on my phone, so sorry if formatting is weird)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? ... different sound? ... clearer sound?

Comment: Consider inserting relevant photos, screenshots or details directly in the question rather than link to an external website. Use [edit].

Comment: Unless you only wish for a modified rather than a different sound, you may have to detect a signal and generate your own sound.  Start by figuring out what you can detect.

Comment: @jsotola i am trying to change the sound to a custom audio

Comment: @AJN it wont let me insert the images or video because the file size is too large